# Can't add column into table - mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table called 'messages'. I wan't to add a column called 'key'.

When I try

```
ALTER TABLE messages ADD key BIGINT(20);
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'bigint(20)' at line 1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post the add column query here

Comment: @MayankPandeyz: it is posted. It is the first code fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax highlighting already shows the problem: **`key` is a keyword** (yeah I know that sounds funny). You can use backquotes to specify the column name:

```
ALTER TABLE messages ADD `key` BIGINT(20);
--                       ^   ^ backquotes
```

Mind that the backquotes are **not** part of the name of the column: the name of the column will be `key`. By using a backquote you state explicitly that you write a column name, not the keyword `key`.

Comment: It worked. But are there any ways to remove the backquotes from the key when displayed in the table?

Comment: @JonasSH: the backquotes are **not** part of the column name. The backquotes are only used to say that you specify the name `key`, not the keyword key.

Comment: @JonasSH, backquotes doesn't get stored in DB. moreover stop using reserve/key words for tabl/column names

Answer (score 3):

Because key is a keyword in mysql. [Reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

You can use

```
ALTER TABLE messages ADD `key` BIGINT(20);
```

by escaping the word key you should be fine with this query.

Answer (score 1):

Always add ` backquotes around keywords.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `key` is a reserve word in *MySQL* and thus needs to be escaped using backtique like

```
ALTER TABLE messages ADD `key`
```

(OR) using double quotes `""` (ANSI92 standard) like

```
 ALTER TABLE messages ADD "key"
```

Better yet, stop using reservewords/keywords for table/column names (in fact for any DB object names)